# How can I force all events from one device to be handled by one window, while allowing all other events from all other devices to be handled normally?

Tags: x11, keyboard-events

I have an application that is used as a control system for a presentation, under Linux and using X11. I have a USB presentation remote that acts as a very miniature keyboard (four buttons: Page Up, Page Down, and two others) which can be used to advance and go back in the presentation. I would like to have my presentation application to receive all of the events from this remote regardless of where the mouse focus is. But I would also like to be able to receive the normal mouse and keyboard events if the current window focus is on the presentation application. Using `XIGrabDevice()` I was able to receive all events from the remote in the presentation application regardless of the current focus but I was not able to receive any events from the mouse or keyboard while the grab was active.

Comment: Remap the buttons to some unique keys (i.e. not XK_Page_Up  but somethning like XK_F35), and define them as hotkeys for your window.

Comment: This looks doable, but I'm having trouble finding the syntax on actually remapping the keys. I'd like to use keys that are not being used by any other application. I see keycodes 250-253 would probably be ideal, but how do I do the remapping?

Comment: I haven't tried to remap keys on just one keyboard out of many so I cannot give you much off advice here, but try starting from here http://www.pixelbeat.org/docs/xkb_remap/

Comment: n.m.: thanks for the link. I have been doing some further research and this information is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up setting up a separate program to capture the remote's keys, then I relay those keys to my main program. I did it this way because the original program was using the older XInput extension, and I needed to use the newer XInput2 extension, and they do not exist well together. Here's some C++ code (it doesn't do any error checking, but this should be done in a real program):

```
// Open connection to X Server
Display *dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL);

// Get opcode for XInput Extension; we'll need it for processing events
int xi_opcode = -1, event, error;
XQueryExtension(dpy, "XInputExtension", &xi_opcode, &event, &error);

// Allow user to select a device
int num_devices;
XIDeviceInfo *info = XIQueryDevice(dpy, XIAllDevices, &num_devices);
for (int i = 0; i < num_devices; ++i)
{
    XIDeviceInfo *dev = &info[i];
    std::cout << dev->deviceid << " " << dev->name << "\n";
}
XIFreeDeviceInfo(info);

std::cout << "Enter the device number: ";
std::string input;
std::cin >> input;
int deviceid = -1;
std::istringstream istr(input);
istr >> deviceid;

// Create an InputOnly window that is just used to grab events from this device
XSetWindowAttributes attrs;
long attrmask = 0;
memset(&attrs, 0, sizeof(attrs));
attrs.override_redirect = True;   // Required to grab device
attrmask |= CWOverrideRedirect;

Window win = XCreateWindow(dpy, DefaultRootWindow(dpy), 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, InputOnly, CopyFromParent, attrmask, &attrs);

// Make window without decorations
PropMotifWmHints hints;
hints.flags = 2;
hints.decorations = 0;
Atom property = XInternAtom(dpy, "_MOTIF_WM_HINTS", True);
XChangeProperty(dpy, win, property, property, 32, PropModeReplace, (unsigned char *)&hints, PROP_MOTIF_WM_HINTS_ELEMENTS);

// We are interested in key presses and hierarchy changes. We also need to get key releases or else we get an infinite stream of key presses.
XIEventMask evmasks[1];
unsigned char mask0[XIMaskLen(XI_LASTEVENT)];
memset(mask0, 0, sizeof(mask0));
XISetMask(mask0, XI_KeyPress);
XISetMask(mask0, XI_KeyRelease);
XISetMask(mask0, XI_HierarchyChanged);
evmasks[0].deviceid = XIAllDevices;
evmasks[0].mask_len = sizeof(mask0);
evmasks[0].mask = mask0;
XISelectEvents(dpy, win, evmasks, 1);

XMapWindow(dpy, win);
XFlush(dpy);

XEvent ev;
bool grab_success = false, grab_changed;
while (1)
{
    grab_changed = false; 
    if (!grab_success)
    {
        XIEventMask masks[1];
        unsigned char mask0[XIMaskLen(XI_LASTEVENT)];
        memset(mask0, 0, sizeof(mask0));
        XISetMask(mask0, XI_KeyPress);
        masks[0].deviceid = deviceid;
        masks[0].mask_len = sizeof(mask0);
        masks[0].mask = mask0;
        XIGrabDevice(dpy, deviceid, win, CurrentTime, None, XIGrabModeAsync, XIGrabModeAsync, XIOwnerEvents, masks);
    }
    XNextEvent(dpy, &ev);
    XGenericEventCookie *cookie = &ev.xcookie;
    if (cookie->type == GenericEvent && cookie->extension == xi_opcode && XGetEventData(dpy, cookie))
    {
        if (cookie->evtype == XI_KeyPress)
        {
            XIDeviceEvent *de = (XIDeviceEvent*)cookie->data;
            std::cout << "found XI_KeyPress event: keycode " << de->detail << "\n";
        }
        else if (cookie->evtype == XI_HierarchyChanged)
        {
            // Perhaps a device was unplugged. The client is expected to re-read the list of devices to find out what changed.
            std::cout << "found XI_HierarchyChanged event.\n";
            grab_changed = true;
        }
        XFreeEventData(dpy, cookie);
    }

    if (grab_changed)
    {
        XIUngrabDevice(dpy, deviceid, CurrentTime);
        grab_success = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

I found the following links helpful:

Peter Hutterer's 6-part blog on XInput2: [1](http://who-t.blogspot.com/2009/05/xi2-recipes-part-1.html) [2](http://who-t.blogspot.com/2009/06/xi2-recipies-part-2.html) [3](http://who-t.blogspot.com/2009/06/xi2-recipes-part-3.html) [4](http://who-t.blogspot.com/2009/07/xi2-recipes-part-4.html) [5](http://who-t.blogspot.com/2009/07/xi2-recipes-part-5.html) [6](http://who-t.blogspot.com/2009/07/xi2-recipes-part-6.html)

This blog entry was useful to determine which class to cast the cookie->data pointer to, depending on the cookie->evtype: [7](https://www.clearchain.com/blog/posts/xinput-1-xinput-2-conversion-guide)